# Difference between ReentrantLock and AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Can someone give me some examples to distinguish ReentrantLock and AbstractQueuedSynchronizer, under what circumstances, should I go for ReentrantLock, verse vice, when should I use AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any practical example of LockSupport & AbstractQueuedSynchronizer use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311811/any-practical-example-of-locksupport-abstractqueuedsynchronizer-use)

Comment: It is a different question tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when should I use AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Probably never.  Look at my answer in the link  of the comments to see uses of AQS.  AQS is a class that offers support for concurrent constructs.  If you are not writing some kind of of lower level concurrency tool you should never use AQS.  Most, if not all, barriers offered in j.u.c should suffice.

> Can someone give me some examples to distinguish ReentrantLock and
>   AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

A better question is distinguish the differences between the ReentrantLock and

- Semaphore
- CyclicBarrier
- ReentrantReadWriteLock
- CountDownLatch

Each of these classes utilize AQS for concurrency support.