# Can `LockSupport.park()` replace `Object.wait()`?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait

Currently I'm learning concurrency programming in Java. I notice `LockSupport.park()` introduced in Java 1.6 is much easier than `Object.wait()` to use, a typical usage of `Object.wait()` is like

```
// Thread1
synchronized (lock) {
    while (condition != true) {
        lock.wait()
    }

    // do stuff
}

// Thread2
synchronized (lock) {
    condition = true;
    lock.notify();
}
```

And I think I can rewrite it using `LockSupport.park()` like

```
// Thread1
while (condition != true) {
    LockSupport.park();
}

// do stuff

// Thread2
condition = true;
LockSupport.unpark(Thread1);
```

By using `LockSupport.park()`, tedious `synchroinzed` block disappears.

My question is, should I always prefer `LockSupport.park()` than `Object.wait()`? Is there any aspect that `Object.wait()` does better than `LockSupport.park()` such as performance?

Comment: I'm not sure, but one thing that comes to mind is that it's not clear from the docs whether LockSupport's methods provide any of the memory visibility guarantees that synchronization provides (happens-before edges and all that).

Comment: See also question [Practical examples of LockSupport/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311811/any-practical-example-of-locksupport-abstractqueuedsynchronizer-use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two things, wait and park, seem alike but they're pretty different.

Calls to `wait` happen in the context of locking with `synchronized`. You have some condition the thread is testing, where you're testing the state of the object you're synchronizing on, to decide if the thread can proceed. The wait/notify process uses the lock as a middleman for sending notifications where the OS scheduler is in charge of who gets notified. So the use case here is that you have some component with state you want to protect from concurrent access and if a thread can't make progress, you want it to wait until it can.

A core part of this is that you are not playing puppet master with the waiting threads, your code doesn't care who gets notified next, that gets delegated to the scheduler.

For park, things are different, there is no locking like what you have with wait, and it is much more of a hands-on puppet master situation. Your code is telling individual threads to go dormant or wake up.

There is a warning in [the API documentation for LockSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html):

> These methods are designed to be used as tools for creating higher-level synchronization utilities, and are not in themselves useful for most concurrency control applications. The park method is designed for use only in constructions of the form:

```
 while (!canProceed()) { ... LockSupport.park(this); }
```

> where neither canProceed nor any other actions prior to the call to park entail locking or blocking. Because only one permit is associated with each thread, any intermediary uses of park could interfere with its intended effects.

Your specific example depends on having a lock around the test for the condition, which is what the documentation is telling you not to do with park. Also you need the lock around the "do stuff" part after the wait.

If you are needing something more powerful than `synchronized` then you might look at ReentrantLock or at different nonblocking approaches but park/unpark is more of a low-level helper than something ready to use in your application.

Note in your second example your condition needs to be volatile or Atomic or otherwise something where its updates are visible across threads.

Comment: After exploring javadoc of related Classes, I have realized that replacement for `wait()` is `Condition`, and for `synchroinzed` it is `Lock`. `Condition` need to be derived from `Lock` also mirrors the relationship of `wait()` and `synchronized`. `LockSupport.park()` is the base of them.

Answer (score 1):

No, Locksupport.park()/unpark() can't replace Object.wait().

Locksupport.park()/unpark() doesn't require you to acquire a lock, but Object.wait() does require you to have synchronized keyword to protect it. Let me tell you why,

```
while (condition != true) 
  LockSupport.park();
```

Without synchronized or other protections, some other threads can change the condition variable between these two lines of code.  So your code might park/unpark when it really shouldn't.